# Initiating a GET request to Django web api and send a list of ids as an array

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to call a rest API in django and send a list of Ids as a paremeter (I can't use query string).

This works if I send only one, but how to specify it for an array of integers:

```
path('details/<int:id>/', views.get_details),

def get_details(request, id=0)
```

What if I have a method that will take a list of Ids:

```
def get_data(request, ids=[])
```

How should the url be defined so that the ids array is populated?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse ids list manually like this

```
path('details/<ids>/', views.get_details),

def parse_ids(ids: str):
    result = []
    for id in ids.split(','):
        try:
            result.append(int(id))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return result

def get_details(request, ids):
    id_list = parse_ids(ids)
    # do stuff
    ...
```